# Component events in usercontrol dll

Tags: c#, events, dll, user-controls

I create a usercontrol dll, I put a dataGridView and a few buttons in this usercontrol dll.

When the main program reference the usercontrol dll, I want the main program to be able to edit the CellFormatting event of dataGridView.

I added code to usercontrol dll

```
public event DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler OnDgvData_CellFormatting;
private void DgvData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
     this.OnDgvData_CellFormatting.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

I can edit the CellFormatting event of usercontrol's dataGridView in the main program.

```
private void UserControl_OnDgvData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    //edit...
}
```

But if I do not create an event using UserControl_OnDgvData_CellFormatting in the main program，
Exceptions will occur during execution.

system.nullreferenceexception object reference not set to an instance of an object.

How should I modify my code to avoid this situation?

Comment: Please do not post code as an image, post it as plain text in the question itself. Please see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: *"I want the main program to be able to edit the CellFormatting event of dataGridView"*. That statement makes no sense. Do you actually mean that you want to main program to be able to handle that event of the grid?

Comment: It's bad practice to start the name of an event with "On". The convention throughout .NET is that an event is named "X" and the method that raises that event is named "OnX". I suggest that you read [this](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html) to learn a bit more about the conventions of raising your own events.

Comment: Personally, I would name your event `GridCellFormatting`. For a form hosting your user control, the field name you used for the grid internally is irrelevant, so naming the event after that is a bad idea. The host only cares about what the event is for and it's for formatting a cell of the grid. You could also add a method named `OnGridCellFormatting` to raise that event. The method is not necessary but, as you'll see if you read my blog post linked to above, that method can be overridden in derived classes to add extra behaviour around the event.

Comment: @jmcilhinney You are right。I renamed the my event GridCellFormatting。And this usercontrol dll，the dataGridView event "private void DgvData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)"，This should be rename & changed to "virtual protected void OnDgvData_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)" ?

Comment: A method that handles an event is generally named `TheObject_TheEvent`, where `TheObject` is the field referring to the object that raises the event and `TheEvent` is the event being handled. A method that raises an event is generally named `OnTheEvent`, where `TheEvent` is the event being raised. If you were to follow convention, you would have two methods: one to handle the grid's event and one to raise the user control's event, with the former calling the latter. The latter method can be omitted if you know you will never need to override it. Just follow those rules.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```cs
this.OnDgvData_CellFormatting.Invoke(sender, e);
```

is saying "invoke the registered event handler(s) for the `OnDgvData_CellFormatting` event". Of course that throws an exception if there is no registered event handler. `OnDgvData_CellFormatting` is basically a field that refers to the delegate(s) that will handle the event. If no event handlers are registered, that field will be `null`. If you check out any examples of raising your own event you will see that they either do this:

```cs
if (this.OnDgvData_CellFormatting != null)
{
    this.OnDgvData_CellFormatting.Invoke(sender, e);
}
```

or, since null-propagation has been supported, this:

```cs
this.OnDgvData_CellFormatting?.Invoke(sender, e);
```

In both cases, the code is saying "invoke the registered event handler(s) for the `OnDgvData_CellFormatting` event if and only if there is one or more event handlers registered".